# Error in reading dat file in matlab installed on linux using textread (Error using fullfile)

Tags: linux, matlab

I'm reading a dat file using textread.

the code works fine on the Matlab in windows, but shows an error in linux:

```
input_file = "/home/ec2-user/mydat.dat";
[a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i] = textread(input_file,'%s%s%d%d%f%f%f%f%*f%*f%*f%*f','delimiter',',');
```

The error is as bellow:

```
Error using fullfile (line 51)
String input not supported.
Error in textread (line 151)
if (noargname(@exist,varargin{1}) ~= 2 || noargname(@exist,fullfile(cd,varargin{1})) ~= 2)
```

Changing "textread" to "txtscan" shows another error:

```
Error using textscan
Too many output arguments.
```

changing to:

```
res_txtscan = textscan(input_file,'%s%s%d%d%f%f%f%f%*f%*f%*f%*f','delimiter',',');
a = res_txtscan{1}
```

the result is:

```
a =

  0×1 empty cell array
and same result for b~i
```

The version of Matlab on Windows is R2014a and on Linux: 20107a.

Comment: This is because of the differing MATLAB versions.  R2017a now introduces a `string` type instead of a character array, so the requirements of `textread` are now different.  You don't have to change anything when you use `textscan`.  Just use it the same way as `textread` and this is now recommended as of R2017a.

Comment: The output of `textscan` is a cell array.  You will have to index into each cell to extract `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.  `C = textread(...); a = C{1}; b = C{2}; ...`.

Comment: please check the updated question again, thanks